# My soql select is timedout sometimes

Tags: soql, timeout

I have a soql query inside my apex class :

```
SELECT Id, Name, account.name, Special_food_requirements__c,Passport_number__c,account.Relationship__c,Function__c
                     FROM Contact
                     WHERE accountId IN :selectedAccountIds
                     AND Id Not IN(SELECT contact__c FROM Visit_contact__c WHERE Visit__c =:visitId)
                     order by account.Name ASC,Name ASC limit 1000
```

Soumetimes, for some users I get timeout.

How can I fix it ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE user26266. You don't yet have the reputation to comment under anyone's post other than your own. Your other post should have either been an edit to this post or a comment under it. What I'd recommend is that you use apex to sort the results of your query rather than doing the Order By. Keith C is on-target about the query plan tool to see if there's some way to reconstruct it to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

Your query uses 'anti-patterns' and doesn't use indexed fields that's why it sometimes times out on you. The `Id Not IN(SELECT contact__c` is not an efficient way to query because it requires the SOQL engine to look through every record. On top of that you then use an ORDER BY clause that's 2 levels deep on fields that aren't indexed. The ORDER BY takes a lot of time for the query engine to perform, particularly since you're using fields from two different objects. While they're both indexed, the fact they're from different object likely makes it more difficult for the order by to take place. You might want to look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Comment: Thank you guys! @crmprogdev do u think my problem will be solved if i split my soql request to 4 requests inside my apex class ?

Answer (score 3):

Learn about and use the [Query Plan Tool](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000199003) to find out what is going wrong and then work on a fix based on that knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid NOT IN for sure, but you can also set the Timeout depending on what language you are using.  This is how in C# for example.

```
private static SforceService binding;

binding.QueryOptionsValue = new QueryOptions();
binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 2000;
binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = true;
binding.Timeout = 180000;
```